# how to switch GCP authentication account for dbt-BigQuery runs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, dbt

I have two GCP accounts. they have different access permissions to different GCP BigQuery datasets, for which I need to run dbt in different scenarios.

Right now, I use oauth method in dbt_profile as below.

```
dbt_project:
  target: default
  outputs:
    default:
      type: bigquery
      method: oauth
```

When I do `dbt run` in CLI the first time, It will ask for gcp oauth login.

Now the question is, how do I switch my GCP accounts between runs of `dbt run` when I need to?

Answer (score 4):

I found the dbt is using `application-default` in gcloud auth.

So the way to switch to a different GCP account is to do

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

it prompts the browser to log in with another GCP account.