# How to use a different account for OAuth with dbt-core and profiles.yml?

Tags: google-bigquery, oauth, dbt

I have a dbt-core project with the following projects.yml:

```
test:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: bigquery
      method: oauth
      project: my-project-id-123456
      dataset: dbt_name
      location: EU
      threads: 8
```

I had 2 Google accounts (private + business) with the same email name for some unknown reason and had to delete the private account to be able to use the business account fully. But I had already used OAuth with the now deleted account and everytime I try to run dbt-core now I get the following error:

```
Runtime Error
  Unable to generate access token, if you're using impersonate_service_account make sure your initial account has the "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator" role on the account you are trying to impersonate.

('invalid_grant: Account has been deleted', {error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Account has been deleted'})
```

I can't find a way to use my other account for OAuth? Already deleted my whole .venv folder and reinstalled dbt-bigquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently dbt-core uses gcloud cli for OAuth. You can reforce a relogging (and choose a new account there) via this answer: [how to switch GCP authentication account for dbt-BigQuery runs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67608814/how-to-switch-gcp-authentication-account-for-dbt-bigquery-runs)

> So the way to switch to a different GCP account is to do
>
> ```
> gcloud auth application-default login
> ```
>
> in the google cloud cli.

I used the locally installed gcloud cli, I don't know if it works with the BQ shell in BQ directly.